# Broken css works only on homepage - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm a codeigniter beginner and trying to link template with it. I haven't touched anything in config yet ( Except base_url() ), whenever I visit the home page that is http://localhost:1234/ci/ everything loads correctly but when I load another controller with url: http://localhost:1234/ci/index.php/register then I see the web page with broken css.

However localhost:1234/ci/index.php?/register loads correctly. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `localhost` url's can-not work here. They can not even work on the person sitting next to you..

Comment: Besides no one here has a crystal ball to look inside your localhost so you may please update your question with some relevant code snippet if possible.

Comment: if it loads with ? then its .htaccess problem ,usually we "hide" index.php see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783666/codeigniter-htaccess-and-url-rewrite-issues

Comment: @Rohit - Yes I know that localhost doesn't work for anyone, was just trying my luck if someone faced something similar to my problem.

Comment: @Nassim- Thank you for your help, it's really appreciated.

Comment: It could be possible you are using relative links for CSS file. Try with absolute link and check if working i.e. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:1234/ci/assets/css/style.css">` pressuming you have directory `assets/css` in root.

Comment: @Tpojka - I did use the exact absolute link like yours but unfortunately the codeigniter script was re-generating the link to http://localhost:1234/ci/index.php/assets/css/style.css. Anyway, thanks for your help, I've got it solved by hiding the index.php from url

Comment: On the your register controller do you have a header view and footer view. Also it could be because of your htaccess on main directory if you have any. Do not touch the htaccess in the application folder.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 - You got it right. I had header and footer view included in register.php view file also at first I did make the changes to htaccess in application folder.