# url rewriting htaccess , codeigniter only load my index page

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, url-rewriting

I am stuck with this problem since hours, if someone can help me it would be really great, all is in the title codeigniter only load my index page even thought the url is changing and my functions called. I activated the mod_rewrite and my config variable are set ($config['index_page'] = ''; and base_url() as well) If someone have an idea! here i show you my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ EHA/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Your project is in a folder ? what is your base_url ?

Comment: yes my project is in the folder EHA and here my base_url $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/EHA/';

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783666/codeigniter-htaccess-and-url-rewrite-issues

Comment: Are you using wamp or xampp

Comment: And what version of CI

Comment: i am using mamp and my version is the 3.0.4

Comment: Try some of these htaccess https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: thank you for your answer! unfortunately none of the .htaccess that you linked me worked :/ i wonder if the problem can come from somewhere else, i also tried all the different 'uri_protocol' and its not working neither

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

Just replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

and also replace

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost:8888/EHA/';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';

$config['base_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';
```

AND IN HTACCESS FILE put following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @Théo Quemar : Hope u understand

Comment: thank you for your answer i did all what you advice but its still not working and i can't call any other functions except the default of my controller i tried each uri_protocol as well and it is not working either

Comment: any other idea what it could be ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
If **.htaccess** file not add.
Add this **.htaccess** file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    #RewriteRule ^muser/([0-9]+) muser/index/$1
</IfModule>
```

**config.php** and do following replaces

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
```