# I have a trouble with my codeigniter program

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i have build some program with Codeigniter 3, but i have a problem when i try to update setting the variable of input is Undefined.

[image: Form Code]

When i try to get site_title input with $_POST['site_title'], i see this error:
[image: Error]

and when i try to get with $this->input->post('site_title'), error: Access to my web was denied.

but in a local server, all proses running well.
please help me!! thanks

Comment: I think it's on your htaccess . Please, take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783666/codeigniter-htaccess-and-url-rewrite-issues

Comment: paste your code as text instead image

Comment: My head hurts - you're doing something wrong though if you're using `$_POST` in CodeIgniter https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: but if i use $this->input->post(); the page is not available

Comment: and i try to make new form on top and i try to get value on form, i get it. i'm so confused.