# Submit route failed - Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have this controllers/insert.php as my controller
and this is the localhost url

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/insert/data_submit/
```

but when I click on submit button it redirects to this link

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.html/insert/data_submit/
```

I'm quite new to Codeigniter and I'm trying out how to insert data into database, but routing is yet complicated to me, can someone explain why this problem shows in my code? ::thanks in advance::

codes in View/insert.php

```
            <?php echo form_open('insert/data_submit/'); ?>
                        <table width="500" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="85"></td>
                                <td width="200" colspan="2">
                                <?php 
                                if (isset($ins_msg)) 
                                {
                                    echo $ins_msg;
                                } ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> Fullname: </td>
                                <td> <input type="text" name="full_name" value="<?= set_value('full_name'); ?>"> </td>
                                <td> <?= form_error('full_name'); ?> </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> Email: </td>
                                <td> <input type="text" name="email" value="<?= set_value('email'); ?>"> </td>
                                <td> <?= form_error('email'); ?> </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="223">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" alt="Login"> </td>
                            </tr>   
                        </table>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Show your view file's code

Comment: @NaimMalek done

Comment: Please first apply htaccess for remove index.php on URL : `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783666/codeigniter-htaccess-and-url-rewrite-issues`

Comment: Your form action is `insert/data_submit/` so it's fine will redirect(will also post form data) to `http://localhost/codeigniter/index.html/insert/data_submit/`, What is your function name at where you want to get form data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Sure your config.php file settings is correct (application/config/cong.php) as follows.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Also please check autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file','form');
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! I'll remember this option for now on.